# Python - Intersection of sets returns only the first value

Tags: python, set, set-intersection

If I input three names (Rolf, Charlie, Mike) the `friends_nearby_set intersection` returns only the first input (Rolf).

If I input (Charlie, Rolf, Mike) the `friends_nearby_set intersection` returns only (Charlie).

Expected output from `friends_nearby_set intersection` should be (Rolf, Charlie).

The author's code returns correct value in video tutorial I'm watching. But for some reason for me it isn't return a proper intersection. Any explanation?

```
friends = input('Enter three friends name, separated by commas (no spaces, please): ').split(',')

people = open('people.txt', 'r')
people_nearby = [line.strip() for line in people.readlines()]

people.close()

friends_set = set(friends)
people_nearby_set = set(people_nearby)

friends_nearby_set = friends_set.intersection(people_nearby_set)

nearby_friends_file = open('nearby_friends.txt', 'w')

for friend in friends_nearby_set:
    print(f'{friend} is nearby! Meet up with them.')
    nearby_friends_file.write(f'{friend}\n')

nearby_friends_file.close()
```

Here is a screenshot during debugging.

[image: debug]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the output before you input the names *Enter three friends name, separated by commas (no spaces, please)*

python sets might be case sensitive try to remove space between comma and the next name
here is example

```
set_1 = {'Rolf', ' Charlie'}
set_2 = {'Rolf', 'Charlie'}

print(set_1.intersection(set_2))
```

output

```
{'Rolf'}
```

not `{'Rolf', 'Charlie'}` because the first got space before. so make attention when you input names input them like `Rolf,Charlie,Mike`

and also try to remove extra spaces before and after the input like the following

```
friends = input('Enter three friends name, separated by commas (no spaces, please): ').strip().split(',')
```

And I saw here how you're writing might be the source of the error to
just open file in the append mode instead of writing mode

> `nearby_friends_file = open('nearby_friends.txt', 'w')`

to

> `nearby_friends_file = open('nearby_friends.txt', 'a')`

because `w` will overwrite the file while `a` will append on the file